# How to make an infinite scrolling list view based on a finite list of items in flutter?

Tags: flutter, listview, dart, scroll, infinite

I searched if I could find a solution but the only results I have is to make an infinite scrolling ListView on a an infinite list of items which load new items when the bottom is reached (like instagram feed).
My problem is that i have a list of something like 10 or 15 items in a little ListView and i would like the user to be able to scroll up or down navigating infinitely in the list of items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a flutter plugin carousel_slider to achieve this.
You will be able to create infinite scroll for both direction i.e. vertical and horizontal.
For more information visit [carousel slider](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider)

There is one more which might help you
[flutter swiper](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_swiper)